# Ruby on Rails Accessing hidden values from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do i access hidden value fields from the controller class.

my hidden value field is

```
<input id="user_id" name="user.id" size="30" type="text" value="<%= @user.id %>" />
```

currently  i am trying to access with @user.id ,
@user = User.find(@user.id)
but its generating error like

" Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id "

then how do i access the above hidden value

thank in advance,
Mahesh

Comment: Your post is corrupted, you'd better edit it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of your field to `user_id` to be more traditional.

You access any POST/GET data with the `params` hash.

```
# your controller
params[:user_id]
# => "field_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Two quick notes. I'd avoid depending on the `user_id` as submitted by a form, it's easy to forge. It's better to pull it from your authentication in the controller create, update, or delete method.

Second, I'd look into form helpers, such as `hidden_field` within a [`form_for`](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M002426&name=form_for) or a [`fields_for`](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M002427&name=fields_for).

```
<% form_form @some_model do %>
   <%= f.hidden_field(:some_field_on_the_model) %>
   <%= hidden_field(:some_model, :some_field) %>
```

Then you use the previously detailed params hash to pull out the values back in the controller.

```
mymodel = MyModel.find(params[:some_field])
```